# how to show two different values in one row of UITable?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have one NSMutableArray having two strings in it

how I want my result in a row of table with some space as like below

Hotel Royal ***_*__**  First

Hotel Taj ***_*____** Second

here _ ----> spaces

if you can't understand my question, you can ask me again regarding it

Thanks in Advance, I do upvote and appreciate proper answer...

Comment: you want to print the two strings on the same row with some gap.....and these two strings u are fetching form an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either you use a custom cell or you use plain UITableViewCells.
This is the code you could use for a standard UITableViewCell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    //cell.textLabel.text = [array1 objectAtIndex:indexpath.row]; // Hotel Royal
    //cell.detailTextLabel.text = [array2 objectAtIndex:indexpath.row]; // First
    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:0]; // Hotel Royal
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:1]; // First
    return cell;
}
```

instead of UITableViewCellStyleValue1 you can test if one of the other styles suits your needs. UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle or UITableViewCellStyleValue2

Comment: I don't have two arrays, I have only one array with two NSStrings saved in it, do you understand theme?

Comment: so your problem is not the display in the table but how to get the values from the array?

Comment: both, first I have to get both values of array and then display on different labels of same row

Comment: it is indexPath, and u wrote indexpath, it is capital 'p' in Path, I removed the error but result is not what I want

Answer (score 0):

You have to add two different UILables to the contentview of the cell if you want the text to appear on same line.

Check this great tutorial for code samples: [Easy custom UITableView drawing](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html)

Chapter *Layout within the contentView* answers your question.